# perform echo xyz | ssh ... with python

Tags: python, pexpect

how to perform

```
echo xyz | ssh [host]
```

(send xyz to host)
with python?

I have tried pexpect

```
pexpect.spawn('echo xyz | ssh [host]')
```

but it's performing

```
echo 'xyz | ssh [host]'
```

maybe other package will be better?

Comment: Check out [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) if you want to do SSH with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn

Gives an example of running a command with a pipe :

```
shell_cmd = 'ls -l | grep LOG > log_list.txt'
child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', shell_cmd])
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Previous incorrect attempt deleted to make sure no-one is confused by it.

Comment: @user4815162342 - I have now edited my answer, and deleted my comments refering to it - care to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `pexpect` to simulate a simple shell pipeline. The simplest way to emulate the pipeline is the `os.system` function:

```
os.system("echo xyz | ssh [host]")
```

A more Pythonic approach is to use [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "host"],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("xyz\n")
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: pexpect is a lot more powerful though if you need to parse the output, and look for things like prompts, errors, etc, but to run a simple subprocess you are right, pexpect is overload.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Agreed. My answer is based on the assumption that the OP needs to port the simple shell pipeline `echo xyz | ssh [host]` to Python. The question doesn't make it clear if this is indeed the case, or if the OP needs `pexpect` for more involved stuff, such as typing in a passphrase and communicating in both directions.